# Netsuite One saved search for two records

Tags: mysql, netsuite

I have created one saved search for a custom record type1. I have a field in this custom record type1  called 'country'. I have another custom record type2. I have two columns in this 'main country' & 'country code'. I need to populate the saved search result in 'country' field with the 'country code' from the custom record type2.
How do I connect the second record type with the saved search of first inorder to return the 'country code' in the country column on running the saved search.

Comment: You mean you like to populate the country code based on country? where country is a different record type and you're using it as a lookup for the second record type. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: There is a NetSuite Help article titled _Creating Custom Fields with Values Derived from Summary Search Results_ that should help you out, but I am having trouble understanding what you are actually trying to accomplish. Do you want to populate a field on a `type1` record with some data from a related `type2` record? Or are you trying to populate a field on `type1` with data from a saved search? If the latter, what is this saved search doing?